# Removing element from HTML form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have element in my HTML form which i want to remove during on load
Here is the element in the form

```
 <input type="hidden" name="testToken" value="1000ad"></input>
```

**what I tried**

```
  $("input[name='testToken']").remove();
```

But i still see the element in HTML when i do view page source . I debugged it in Firefox , this line gets executed successfully without any error in console.

what is the issue here ?

**UPDATE:-**

But if i do below it works. I do not see element when i do view page source. But i

```
 var testElement = document.getElementsByName('testToken');
 testElement[0].remove();
```

But  `testElement[0].remove();` throws error in IE saying `Object doesn't support property or method 'remove'`

Comment: The element will always appear in View Source as it was downloaded from the server. You're removing it from the DOM after the page has been loaded, it will only disappear from the DOM Inspector. There is no issue here, this is standard behaviour. If you don't even want the element to appear in the View Source output then you need to remove it on the server before you send the response.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I got your point. But please see my update then how come another approach works.

Comment: I'm confused how that second snippet can work for two reasons. Firstly, it's removing from the DOM again so has the same issue as the first; ie. it will still be visible in View Source. Secondly, depending on the type of element `testToken` is, `remove()` would most likely throw an error in all browsers, not just IE. Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net showing it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes from js is not solid but it is temporary.

```
$("input[name='testToken']").remove();
```

This line of code removes the DOM element but this can be seen if you see the source of the page via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> for view src.

Instead you should do it serverside.

With PHP as a server side you can do something like:

```
<?php if($somevar != "" || $somevar != null) { ?>
   <input type="hidden" name="testToken" value="1000ad"></input>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I got your point. But please see my update then how come another approach works.

Comment: @user3198603 IE doesn't follow W3C recommendations, they have their own browser engine and about error you can go at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

Comment: @user3198603 `document.removeChild(testElement[0]);` try this.

Comment: you said `This line of code removes the DOM element but this can be seen if you see the source of the page via Ctrl+U for view src. ` i believe youe mean this can not be seen instead of this can be seen. My question is regarding your answer that `Instead you should do it serverside. ` My question how come i am able to remove it through one approach but not thru jquery ?

Comment: @user3198603 see the page written on server is the final piece of page which i going to render in the browser depending on the request made. Although the first comment at your post does really answer it.

Answer (score -1):

just try removing the element with the name attribute, may this will help

```js
function removeInput(){
   $("[name=testToken]").remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <input type="text" name="testToken" value="blabla" /><br/>
  <input type="button" onclick="removeInput()" value="remove" />
  
</body>
```

Comment: Do you know what is the actual discussion is running? You are too far away from the actual question.